# How do I really say "I study in the United States"?

Tags: translation, word-choice

What I came up with is 私はアメリカに留学してる or "I study abroad in America", which is probably the safest option. However, can I express the same without using 留学 explicitly?

私は米国で勉強します "I study in the US" sounds very strange to me. What about 私は米国の大学へ進学した "I entered a university in the US"?

Comment: `アメリカで勉強しています。` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about アメリカの大学で勉強しています. I suggest it

Comment: Assuming that the OP means "I am (currently) studying at a US university", this is also the best answer I can think of.